# How do I remove a list in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016, list

I have a huge Microsoft Word document, in which for some reason, random lines throughout the document got added to a list. It mostly got applied to equations, but sometimes the list got applied to random sentences as well. Here's an example:

[image]

I'd like to remove the entire list - that is, not erase the text, but remove the numbers from all the lines which got added to the list.

How would I do so, without going through them one by one? Thanks!

Comment: Select the list items- go to Home- Paragraph- under list library- select None.

Comment: @Lee thank you, but is there a way to select all the list items at the same time? If my document is 200 pages long, and five lines in each page got added to the same list, I'd rather not select each of them individually